# Integrating real-time components into REST backend

Tags: node.js, rest, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I am implementing a product that will be accessible via web and mobile clients, and am doing thorough research to make sure that I have chosen a good set of tools before I begin. For front-end, I am using AngularJS (Angularjs + angular-ui on web, ionic + cordova on mobile), and because I want to have a single backend serving all types of clients, I plan on implementing a RESTful service (likely one that accepts and returns JSON data). I am leaning towards using Mongo, Node, and Express to create this RESTful API, but am open to suggestions on that front.

But the sticking point for me right now is this: certain parts of the application (including, for example, a live chat/messaging section) need to be real-time. I am aware of the various technologies and protocols for implementing real-time web services (webhooks, websockets, long polling, etc.) and the libraries and frameworks that implement them and expose that functionality (SockJS, Socket.io, etc.) and I want to be clear that I am not asking one of those "what is the best framework" types of questions.

My question is rather about the correct way to implement these two kinds of services side-by-side. Should I be serving the chat separately from the rest of the application? Or is there a clean way to integrate these two different protocols into the same application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The express framework is quite modular so it can sit side by side with a websocket module if you so wish. The most common reason for doing this is to share authentication routines across http and websockets by using the same session store in both modules.

For example you would authenticate a user by http with the express framework when they login, which will allow access to your chat application. From then on you would take advantage of the realtime and speedy protocol of websockets and on your server code you will check the cookie that the client sends with the socket message and check that the request corresponds to an authenticated session from before.

Comment: This was what I was looking for -- do you happen to know of any case studies/examples of this type of implementation that I could look at for reference?

Comment: Yup, this [article](http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth) shows a simple example of using the express session cookie with socket.io.

Answer (score 2):

Many websites use websockets for chat or other push updates, and a separate RESTful API over AJAX, delivered to the same page.  There are great reasons to leave RESTful things as they are, particularly if caching is an issue--websockets won't benefit from web caches outside your servers.  Websockets are better suited for chat on any modern browser, which trades a small keep-alive for a reconnecting long-poll.  So two separate interfaces adds a little complexity that you may benefit from, when scaling and cost-per-user are considered.

If your app grows enough to require this scaling, you'll find this actually simplifies things greatly--clients in the same chat groups can map to the same server, and a load balancer can distribute RESTful calls appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for *one* communication protocol to serve both needs (calling the server from the client, as well as pushing data from the server), you might have a look at [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/).

> WAMP is an open WebSocket subprotocol that provides two application
>   messaging patterns in one unified protocol: Remote Procedure Calls +
>   Publish & Subscribe.

If you want to dig a little deeper, [this](http://wamp.ws/why/) describes the why, the motivation and the design. WAMP has [multiple implementations](http://wamp.ws/implementations/) in different languages.

---

Now, if you want to stick to REST, then you cannot integrate push at the protocol level (since REST simply does not have that), but only at "framework level". You need a 2nd protocol. The options are:

1. WebSocket
2. Server Sent Events (SSE)
3. HTTP Long-Poll

SSE in a way could be a good complement to REST. However, it's unsupported on IE (not even IE11), and it's unclear if it ever will be.

WebSocket obviously works, but then why not have it all running over WebSocket? (This line of thinking leads to WAMP).

So IMO the natural complement for REST would be some HTTP Long-poll based mechanism for simulating push. You can make HTTP Long-poll work robustly. You'll have to live with the inefficiencies and limitations of HTTP (for use cases like this) with this solution then.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hosted real-time messaging (and even storage) service and integrate it into your frontend apps (web and mobile). These services leverage the websocket protocol and normally include HTTP Comet fallbacks.

The cool thing is that you don't need to manage the underlying infrastructure in terms of high-availability and unlimited scalability and focus only on developing a great app.

I work for Realtime so i'm a bit biased but I think the Realtime Framework could help you. More at http://framework.realtime.co